# How do I push to new view controller with code?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.5

The app should forward to another view controller based on some data in a database. The database is working fine, but I can't get the app to forward to the second view controller.
Here's the code I have in place.

```
ssSecondViewController *tempView =[[ssSecondViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tempView animated:YES];
```

I'm not getting any errors but when I run the code the screen forwards to a blank black view?

Comment: I should add that I'm using storyboards and xcode 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have already your viewController on storyboard then you can assign it by like below code & you must have set identifier to viewControler on storyboard

```
ssSecondViewController *tempView =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"];
```

set your viewController id here,in below image identifier is "MenuViewController"

[image]

if it is on .Xib file then

```
ssSecondViewController *tempView =[[ssSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourIdentifier" bundle:nil];
```

if you just want to add new viewController with programmetically without using already available viewController ,then you have to init it with `initWithFrame` then it shows viewController

```
ssSecondViewController *tempView =[[ssSecondViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
```

`ssSecondViewController *tempView =[[ssSecondViewController alloc] init];` this line just allocates the viewController, it not have any location to draw it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your first answer (storyboards) was what I needed. Worked like a charm. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

So for your example it would be:

```
ssSecondViewController *tempView =[[ssSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ssSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

With storyboards you normally do not actually do pushes, you segue using `segueIdentifiers` setup in the storyboard:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ssSecondSegue" sender:self];
```

Then handle data passing and other setters in your `prepareForSegue`